# Problem in running scripts on selenium grid with TestNG

Tags: selenium-grid

i have the test cases with my on framework i.e. my seleniumtestsupport.java file in i uses the webdriver class for starting,stoping & killing the browser.Scripts was running ok with Selenium rc smoothly.Now i want to run multiple scripts through selenium grid on multiple ports.I did setup the grid with testNg and ant.But issue is what changes to be made in the SeeleniumTestSupport.java file or any other files to run the scripts. testng.xml file is also configured. please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium-Grid by itself doesn't do any thing to run tests in parallel. Grid is like mammoth selenium-RC which can execute multiple tests together. But for Grid to execute multiple tests you need to trigger many tests at the same time. For that you will have to use testNG's features.

You can get details on how to use testNG to run multiple tests in parallel from [here](http://testng.org/doc/selenium.html)

You can read more about how Selenium Grid 1.xx works [here](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/). Grid 1.x handles only selenium requests and not webdriver. But it's better you understand how Grid 1.x works.

The next version of Grid (Grid 2.0) was released recently. That handles webdriver tests also. You can download Grid 2.0 from [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc2.jar&can=2&q=) and find more details about Grid [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2)